# where to change the absolute path for uploads? sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir')

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i have this code:

```
 $profile_pic = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/rainbowcode/profilepics/'.$this->msisdn.".png";
```

and changed it to: 
    $profile_pic = '/home/rainbowcode/rainbowcode_deploy_versions/profilepics/'.$this->msisdn.".png";

the above directory path does exist and the actual file also does exist but for some or other reason it is not finding my file???

i found this: http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/upload where it states that you can configure the absolute path in config/config.php but i dont have a config.php

i dont understand, please help
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See documentation about customizing path.
http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_sub_customizing_the_file_structure

You should override `sf_upload_dir` in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`

Comment: my ProjectConfiguration.class does not define sf_upload_dir it only sets the default time zone

Comment: See documentation carefully. It describes how to *override* default value of `sf_upload_dir`

Comment: In my reply i've pointed to a specific place in documentation where overriding of `sf_app_template_dir` was shown. I guess you need just replace `sf_app_template_dir` with `sf_upload_dir` and your cutsom place in that example.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can override setwebdir method in your /config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
public function setWebDir($webDir)
{
    sfConfig::add(array(
      'sf_web_dir'    => $webDir,//dont change this if you dont have to
      'sf_upload_dir' => $webDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads',//thats what you wanted to change :)
    ));
}
```

Check this post:
http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/84548/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to configure upload path.
Please make sure the $this->msisdn returns smth.

Comment: if i use that line i looks for the profile picture in the WRONG directory: web/uploads/rainbowcode/images/profilepics... i moved all profile pictures to the NEW folder /home/rainbowcode/rainbowcode_deploy_versions/profilepics